# How to edit querybuilder to include a cq:page

Tags: aem, jcr, sling

I created a form and added it in geometrixx-gov folder under the dam (`/content/dam/formsanddocuments/geometrixx-gov`) as shown in the image below

[image]

However, this form isn't showing up when I go to `http://localhost:4502/editor.html/content/geometrixx-gov/en/allforms.html`

The `allforms.html` page is using a `querybuilder` to fetch all the forms in `/content/dam/formsanddocuments/geometrixx-gov`. Below is that query from the page

```
        <querybuilder
            jcr:created="{Date}2014-02-17T22:47:37.361+05:30"
            jcr:createdBy="admin"
            jcr:lastModified="{Date}2014-03-28T17:52:05.245+05:30"
            jcr:lastModifiedBy="admin"
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            sling:resourceType="fd/fp/components/querybuilder"
            customStylePath="/etc/designs/geometrixx-gov/form_portal_default.css"
            customTemplate="/etc/designs/geometrixx-gov/fp/card/template.html/jcr:content"
            disableSearch="true"
            folderPaths="/content/dam/formsanddocuments/geometrixx-gov"
            portalTitle="All Forms"
            renderType="[PDF,HTML,GUIDE]"
            singleView="Card"
            style="Custom Style"
            viewSwitch="true">
            <view
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                sling:resourceType="fd/fp/components/lenses/view"/>
            <textbar
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                sling:resourceType="fd/fp/components/predicates/textbar"/>
            <left
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                sling:resourceType="foundation/components/parsys">
                <propertiespredicate
                    jcr:created="{Date}2014-03-28T17:45:35.478+05:30"
                    jcr:createdBy="admin"
                    jcr:lastModified="{Date}2014-03-28T17:50:01.642+05:30"
                    jcr:lastModifiedBy="admin"
                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                    sling:resourceType="fd/fp/components/predicates/propertiespredicate"
                    searchOptionsPredicates="\{&quot;preducateType&quot;:&quot;title&quot;,&quot;statusFilter&quot;:&quot;active&quot;,&quot;captionText&quot;:&quot;Title&quot;,&quot;defaultFilter&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;enabled&quot;:true}"
                    title="Properties"/>
            </left>
            <searchAssets
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                sling:resourceType="fd/fp/search"/>
        </querybuilder>
```

**Question**

What can I do so that the form I added (DORUsingSchema) also shows up in the All Forms page?

Answer (score 0):

How did you create DORUsingSchema Form?
If the form is being created using Forms Manager - http://localhost:4502/aem/forms.html/content/dam/formsanddocuments there are nodes created at two places.

1. /content/dam/formsanddocuments// - This node contains metadata of the form.
2. /content/forms/af// - This is actual form having the same relative hierarchy.

You have copied the node from /content/forms/af/[project-folder]/[formName] to /content/dam/formsanddocuments/[project-folder] which is incorrect, Form Manager take care of creating these nodes.

To show the form in your portal, you need to modify properties predicate applied on the form portal component in allforms.html page. This properties predicate shows all appliations starting with title "Application For", Either you can update your application title or update properties predicate to list down your form in the form portal.

To open properties dialog in authoring mode, click on Search icon located at the leftmost position of search box.